# "Service metadata may not be accessible" after adding EF object to my service contract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF Service using TCP as the protocol for data-sharing. But I ran into a problem after I have added a custom object to my service contract. Before I added this, everything worked fine.

```
[OperationContract]
List<TaskScheduler> GetAllTaskSchedulers();
```

Does anyone know why this happens? This is my .config of my WCF Service

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="PortBinding" portSharingEnabled="true" />
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="NxtTaskService.ServiceContracts.TaskService" behaviorConfiguration="NxtTaskServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/nxtask" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="service" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="NxtTaskService.ServiceContracts.ITaskService" name="tcp" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NxtTaskServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the 64-bit version of IIS Express

Comment: And what is TaskScheduler? Is it marked as a [Datacontract] ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Its a class genereted by Entitfy Framework. Yes it is marked as DataContract